# Split part files based on date column using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have 200 `csv` part files which are separated by year from 2012 till 2018. I further want to split the `csv` files based on the date column which is present in it using `pyspark`. Would like to know an efficient way to do this, since the `csv` would contain millions of rows.

My current approach is to 
- read all the `csv` files for 2012 into a dataframe
- then for all the, 365 days i loop through the above dataframe and then write the contents to the csv by date.

Is there any other efficient way to achieve this pyspark.

I have put sample data below:

```
> 1234|2012-01-01|abc|def|455 
> 
> 1278|2012-04-05|duuj|dea|457
> 
> 9998|2012-05-09|dimd|ase|759
> 
> 8892|2012-01-01|eedbnd|ss|378
> 
> 178|2012-04-05|dswuj|ada|47
> 
> 278|2012-04-05|d32j|d12a|421
```

I need this data to be written into 3 separate csv files containing data for 2012-01-01 , 2012-04-05 and 2012-05-09

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 dates in sample data - 01-01, 04-05, 05-09

```
def fn(dt):
  return hash(dt)
```

Create a key, value pair with key being the date

```
rdd = sc.textFile('path/your_file.txt',3).map(lambda r: r.split('|')).map(lambda r: (r[1],r))
```

Generate a hash for the key and pass it to partitionBy

```
rdd.partitionBy(3, fn).saveAsTextFile('partitioned_parts')
```

You should now see 3 part files each having specific dates.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bala. I created a dataframe from my source data since i had to maintain the order of the columns in the csv created and the I did a partitionBy 'date' column. I ended up writing the data like - df.write.partitionBy("dt").format('csv').mode("overwrite").options(delimiter="|").save("gs://bucket"). This process does my job, but it takes a lot of time to complete when files are 100GB or greater. Is there anyway to speed up the process ? Source has 200 part files.. Will combining the part files into fewer files help here ?